How does the image resolution converts to frequency limits of Fourier space?
Sorry if this question has been asked before.
I have an image that has a dimensions 5x5 um$^{2}$ and resolution 256x256 pixels, and I do a Fourier transform of it. Based on the resolution, I can't resolve things smaller than 5um/256 = 20nm. 20nm corresponds to around 50 um$^{-1}$ in reciprocal space, so I would naively expect the fourier domain to span an area limited by 50 um$^{-1}$. In practice, we get only half of it, the space goes from -25 um$^{-1}$ to 25 um$^{-1}$.
I am not really sure why this is the case. Is it because our best resolution corresponds to only half of the "wave" ?

That’s it. The shortest wave you can draw is one pixel on, one off. That’s a period of 2 pixels. So 1/2 1/px is the highest frequency you have in the frequency domain.

Thank you. I thought maybe this intuition was too simple.
